# Creating input field with unique ID in foreach loop`

Tags: javascript, php, datetimepicker

i have a php foreach loop that successfully creates multiple sections within a modal, each section having it's own Datetimepicker.

I changed the datetimepicker to use a class rather than relying on the ID ( I understand that using the ID as is, the foreach loop gives each datetimepicker the same ID)

However, now, the calendar popup doesn't come up but when I hit the calendar button it populates all the datepicker fields with today's date/time.

I need to either fix this up or find a way to properly iterate through the loop giving each datetimepicker its own unique ID and applying it to the script.

Any help is much appreciated

```
<?php foreach($v as $k=>$n): ?>
<!--Body of the Modal for expired displays-->
<br>
<h6><?php echo $n['Type'] ?></h6>
<h6>Date/Time Expiring: <?php echo $n["Expiration"] ?></h6>
<h6>Set New Expiration:</h6><!--  <input data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"> -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="datepick input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
      <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target=".datepick"/>
      <span class="input-group-addon" data-target=".datepick" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
          <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>                 
<a href="#" style="float:left;">View Display</a>
<br>
<hr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.datepick').each(function(){
      $(this).datetimepicker({
       icons: {
                    time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                    date: "fa fa-calendar",
                    up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                    down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
                }
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="datepick input-group date" id="datetimepicker<?php echo $k; ?>" data-target-input="nearest">
   <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker<?php echo $k; ?>"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker<?php echo $k; ?>" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
   <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('.datepick').each(function(){
  $(this).datetimepicker({
   icons: {
                time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                date: "fa fa-calendar",
                up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
            }
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try to remove the `id="datetimepicker1"`

Comment: I gave that a shot, but no luck unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You're using `data-target=".datepick"` so any single datepicker will have a target all the elements with that class.

I would rollback to the unique ID. Just use the key (`$k`) of the array element as a unique identifier. Something like:

```
<div class="datepick input-group date" id="datetimepicker<?php echo $k; ?>" ...>
```

Comment: How would I need to incorporate that into the script block though?

Comment: Leave the class `.datepick` in order to loop the elements in the script block, but use as `data-target` the ID

Comment: Hmm, ok that makes sense. I updated my code above, it fixed the issue so that the popup is back but if I hit the icon of all 3 fields, it only makes the popup occur in the first one still

Comment: Are you writing the same incremental value both in the `id` and the `data-target`?

Comment: Yes you can see my updated code above. That's what I'm currently doing